# Looping Down A Column in Google Sheets Using Offset and Subtracting 2 Values in a Cell

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing an inventory management script of Google Sheets. What i need to do...

I'm trying to loop down Column 'A' and check to see if a cell in column 'A' has a value. If that row in Column 'A' does have a value then i want to subtract  the Value in Column 'E' from the Value in Column 'A' and then store that result of the difference in Column 'E'. After the program loops all down to the last cell of column A (which is hard coded at 327) then i want all values in Column 'A' to be cleared.

Currently what is happening is the that first row where column 'A' has a value works but after that its all over the place. I think my loop iterations might be wrong but i cant figure it out.

```
function myFunction4() {
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var high = mySheet.getRange("E10");
  var low = mySheet.getRange("A10");

  for (var i = 0; i < 327; i++) {
    if (low.getValue() == 0 ) {
      i = i + 1;
    } else {
      high = high.offset(i, 0);
      low = low.offset(i, 0);
      high.setValue(high.getValue() - low.getValue());
    }

    mySheet.getRange("A10:A328").clearContent();
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Trying to get the program to run as fast as possible!

Comment: You're much better off using a single read (Range#getValues()`) and then working with the resulting JavaScript array, using `Range#setValues` to write the altered array back to the spreadsheet. Such an approach will be considerably faster.